# Comma point formating

Tags: tables

How to solve the problem with commas and points. It works when there are points instead of commas, however, I need commas. Thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}


    \begin{table}[htb]
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
                            c
                            S[table-format=1,6(2)]
                            S[table-format=5,3(2)]
                            S[table-format=1,4(2)]
                            S[table-format=3,1(2)]
                            cc 
                            }
    \toprule
\makecell[t]{Číslo\\ zdroje}
    &   {\makecell[t]{$P$\\ (dny)}}
        &   {\makecell[t]{$T_0$\\ (RJD)}}
            &   {\makecell[t]{$e$}}
                &   {\makecell[t]{$\omega$\\ (\si{\degree})}}
                    &   {\makecell[t]{$i$\\ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)}}
                        &   {\makecell[t]{$a$\\ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)}}    \\
    \midrule
1 & 5,732436(15) & 54002,780(46)  & 0,0910(37) & 149,2(3,0) &   &            \\
2 & 5,732824(3)  & 54002,7241(96) & 0,0858(41) & 145,6(3,9) &   &            \\
3 & 5,732824(1)  & 54002,7775(34) & 0,0883(26) & 149,1(2,3) &   &            \\
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{Pozn:}
Čísla v závorkách jsou chyby posledních uvedených cifer.}
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `output-decimal-marker={,}` to use comma as decimal marker in your output.

Two additional problems:

- you should still use `.` in the table format
- if you mark the uncertainty of a number with the syntax `()` a number containing a decimal marker does not make sense in your example. Maybe you want to give the error instead? Compare these two syntax which mean the same: `\num{9.99(9)}` and `\num{9.99 +- 0.09}`.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\begin{document}


    \begin{table}[htb]
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
                            c
                            S[table-format=1.6(2)]
                            S[table-format=5.3(2)]
                            S[table-format=1.4(2)]
                            S[table-format=3.1(2)]
                            cc 
                            }
    \toprule
\makecell[t]{Číslo\\ zdroje}
    &   {\makecell[t]{$P$\\ (dny)}}
        &   {\makecell[t]{$T_0$\\ (RJD)}}
            &   {\makecell[t]{$e$}}
                &   {\makecell[t]{$\omega$\\ (\si{\degree})}}
                    &   {\makecell[t]{$i$\\ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)}}
                        &   {\makecell[t]{$a$\\ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)}}    \\
    \midrule
1 & 5,732436(15) & 54002,780(46)  & 0,0910(37) & 149,2(3) &   &            \\
2 & 5,732824(3)  & 54002,7241(96) & 0,0858(41) & 145,6(3) &   &            \\
3 & 5,732824(1)  & 54002,7775(34) & 0,0883(26) & 149,1(2) &   &            \\
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{Pozn:}
Čísla v závorkách jsou chyby posledních uvedených cifer.}
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```